# In MySQL, how to run sql in the command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e 'create database mydb;'
```

MySQL version is

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.14, for Win64 (x86)
```

When I run the command, it just shows the help information. Please help.

Comment: it works for me, show the whole console output might be helpful.

Comment: can you please try double quotes in Linux machine ?

Comment: double quotes works in linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your single quotes to double quotes:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "create database mydb;"
```

I'm running mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.16, for Win32 (x86)

Comment: Not for me, but double quotes does. If I use single quotes I only get the help for the command.

Comment: my version is: `Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Comment: @James.Xu: I think Krister Andersson may well be right. Obviously in Bash, single-quotes would work fine; but the OP's MySQL version is `... for Win64 (x86)`, so it's quite plausible that the OP is using the Windows command prompt, which will treat `'create database mydb;'` as three arguments, just like `"'create" database "mydb;'"`.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 7. it has to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You also can echo your sql statement into mysql, e.g.:

```
echo "select sum(table_rows) from information_schema.tables" | mysql -uUSR -pPASSWD
```